# Issue with QTextEdit cursor, when using eventFilters

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

I am facing an issue with QTextEdit. i am using eventFilters for QTextEdit.
When i press keys in the numpad (0-9) in the QTextEdit it will auto compleate the sentense 
which is connected that number. For example

[image]

Everything is working fine but when i type a sentence and press the number 3 in numpad the text related to it is filled in QTextEdit but the  cursor is moved to home. actually it is supposed to be the place where the sentence end.

[image]

Can anyone guide me how to deal with this.

Thanks and Regards,
Sudeepth Patinjarayil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to move the cursor to the end of the document, checkout this example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyWindow(QtGui.QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setPlainText("Hello!")

        cursor = self.textCursor()
        cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.End, QtGui.QTextCursor.MoveAnchor)

        self.setTextCursor(cursor)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')

    main = MyWindow()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```